# display description as per the code values in column of DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I've a DataTable with columns type and type_amount. This DataTable is bind with a gridview `GridView1`.

```
type type_amount
1       50,000
2       60,000
3       90,000
```

I've to show the description of the type_id instead of id's in the gridview, such that my gridview would appear as

```
type type_amount
silk        50,000
siffon      60,000
cotton      90,000
```

How can I do this in DataTable?

```
public void Get_Billing_Type()
{
    try
    {
        DataTable dt = new DAL_Set_Billing_Type().Get_Billing_Type();
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            // how to implement logic ??
        }
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception) {  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer.

```
public void Get_Billing_Type()
{
    try
    {
        DataTable dt = new DAL_Set_Billing_Type().Get_Billing_Type();
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    switch(row[0].ToString())
                    {
                        case "1":
                            {
                                row["type_id"] = "silk";
                                break;
                            }
                        case "2":
                            {
                                row["type_id"] = "siffon";
                                break;
                            }
                        case "3":
                            {
                                row["type_id"] = "cotton";
                                break;
                            }
                    }
                }
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception) {  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
            dt.Columns.Add("type_amount", typeof(int));
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                int value = (int)row["type"];

                switch(value)
                {
                    case 1 :
                        row["type_amount"] = 50000;
                        break;
                    case 2 :
                        row["type_amount"] = 60000;
                        break;
                    case 3 :
                        row["type_amount"] = 90000;
                        break;

                }

            }
```